# RadioButtonList selected index through javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbGender" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>           
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<script type="text/javascript">      

    function GetRDBValue()
    {
        var radio = document.getElementsByName('rdbGender');
        for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++)
        {
            if (radio[i].checked)
            {
                alert(radio[i].value);
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Issue is that i am always getting `radio.length = 0`. Can someone help me, i have searched a lot on the google but the same code is present everywhere.

Comment: there is no element with name `rdbGender` in your code

Comment: If i change it to `getElementById`, then i am still getting `radio.length = 0`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ASP.NET renders transformed mark-up of the actual radio buttons.

Try the following:

```
function GetRDBValue() {
    var rb = document.getElementById("<%=rdbGender.ClientID%>");//Client ID of the radiolist
    var radio = rb.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
        if (radio[i].checked) {
            alert(radio[i].value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by client id ?

Comment: @WaleedNaveed, `ClientID` is the ID for `RadioButtonList` that is generated by ASP.NET....